# How to cancel a "dispatch_get_main_queue" with a Button?

Tags: objective-c, multitasking

I'm trying to coding for a task call API, the problem here is when screen was displayed
a task still run in background:

```
[[JPNetworkingManager sharedManager] getSnapNSendsForLetterWithID:letterID withIsArchived:isArchived completionHandler:^(NSArray *snapNSends, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //do my code
        });
}];
```

So how I can cancel this task? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure this api returns completion once

```
[[JPNetworkingManager sharedManager] getSnapNSendsForLetterWithID
```

Or do this

```
var once = true 

[[JPNetworkingManager sharedManager] getSnapNSendsForLetterWithID:letterID withIsArchived:isArchived completionHandler:^(NSArray *snapNSends, NSError *error) {

    if once { 

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //do my code
       }); 

       once = false
    }
}
```